# Setting up Alerts in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I am running `MOSS 2007` on a `Windows 2003` box. I need to know what configuration must be done to get Alerts to work. `SMTP settings`, etc.... When I create my alert, it is created but it does not send the email to show me that something changed in my document library or on any particular document. What am I missing?

I did install the Email Services under Windows Components and the SMTP under `IIS`.
In my SharePoint Central Admin, I did change my settings for outgoing and incoming email (Under the Topology and Services section).

What else am I missing?

Comment: I was pulled of it and place on another project.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for the Super User exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the Web Application Outgoing E-mail Settings in your Central Administration? Y

Answer (score 0):

Has the SMTP server been configured to allow the MOSS server to relay mail to it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have configured the SMTP server properly by configuring an account and associating to a mail client Outlook. Check the Servers outgoing and incoming capabilites from the mail client first.

Ensure that you have subscribed to the alerts properly in a list

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this question is really appropriate for StackOverflow - its not a programming question, see the FAQ.

But anyway - could be anti-virus or smtp relay rules stopping sharepoint sending smtp to your mail server. Try this tool to diagnose.

http://www.simplecomtools.com/smtptesttool.html

If that doesn't work then its MS support - the newsgroups are littered with the carcasses of people trying to resolve alert email problems!

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i undertand regards to the "its not a programming question" but then they must not allow SharePoint to be a Tag since most of SharePoint is configuration anyways!!